# Xamarin cross-platform module development

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, module, architecture

I need to develop a module for both Android and iOS, which would be used by third-party applications in the future. This module needs to be able to:

- access the database
- call web services
- access the keystore/keychain

Third-party applications will just provide some GUI and feed the module. I would like to write the module just once for both Android and iOS, that is why Xamarin seems to be a reasonable choice.

Some options I have already considered:

- If I did it for Android only, I would create a separate **Service**, that would be bound by the client application. However, there is no way to create a cross-platform service for both Android and iOS in Xamarin if I am not mistaken.
- **Portable Class Library** - it could do the job I need, but I would force authors of third party applications into using C# and Xamarin, which is an obvious problem.

Is there any solution?

Comment: If you want to develop some Module that can be used both by android and ios by other developers (and you don't want it to be a webservice) the only way I see is that you develop a single app, share the files with the apps of the third developers in common folders and see if the apps of the third party developers can call the "module" app.

If not I think they should use the same language, or a compatible one with the api.

Comment: @Mulflar _... and you don't want it to be a webservice_ - that is an interesting idea. Is it possible to host a local web server on Android and iOS? I doubt it, but it could solve my issue...